# Trying to overwrite pre populated data in an input area

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am trying to display an input area in a Jade file with pre-populated data gathered from the session info being stored in mongodb session store. The web app is built on Express for node.js. My Jade file looks like this with the input area (pre-populated with session data):

```
            input(name='username', value='#{username}')
```

So the input area is displaying the correct username stored in the session. Then, I want the user to be able to edit that field and submit a new username if desired. My mongodb update() looks like this:

```
uname = request.body.username;
targetcol.update({username: req.session.username, password: req.session.password}, {username: uname});
```

Once submitted however, the document in the mongodb collection for the related profile is not being updated, it's keeping the same value that's been pre-populated. I'm wondering if this is because I'm assigning it as a `value=` in the Jade file? Any advice on what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a form, access the `value` attribute of the input with name `username` from your route handler function using `req.body.username`:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  var newUsername = req.body.username;
  targetcol.update({ username: req.session.uname, password: req.session.password}
  , {username: newUsername});
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: make sure that the input is part of the correct form, make sure you don't have a duplicate input element that is also named `username`. add a `console.log(newUsername)` to check whether the correct thing gets to the route handler. if it's correct, then there is probably a problem with the code that writes it to mongo; if it's incorrect, the problem is likely in your html form

Comment: looks to be an issue with the mongodb update I'm doing, the passed in values from req.body look correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was on the mongodb update() side of things. I left a big part out of my question apparently... The selection criteria was actually this:

```
input(name='username', value='#{username}', disabled)
```

I didn't realize `disabled` fields would pass in undefined values, I just thought it made them un-editable. So the update() wasn't working because it couldn't find any matching documents in the collection because `username` was `undefined`. You know what they say about assumptions!

I'll credit you @Plato with the answer though, the hint to investigate the values is what lead me to figure this out.

Comment: thanks! btw you should directly pass the variable to the attribute: `input(name='username', value=username, disabled)` also my personal preference is to explicitly use `disabled="disabled"` but i think it works fine with just `disabled` as you have it